# Integrating over two functions with different number of points

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I am trying to integrate a function that is a fraction where both numerator and denominator have a different number of points. So, I am trying to solve this integral $\int_{0}^{4} \frac{exp(\frac{\Delta F(z)}{RT})}{B(z)}dz$, where both numerator and denominator has different number of points. While the numerator has 100's of points between 0 to 4, the denominator has only 41 points between 0 to 4. So, how can I solve this integral numerically? Shall I just plot both the functions, and find the area between them, or are there any methods that I can implement? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select a new set of nodes. Interpolate the value of the numerator and the denominator at each new node using the information that you have already. Do numerical integration using the new nodes and your approximation of the associated function values. Use a pair of methods that have the *same* order of accuracy. If you interpolated linearly between pairs of nodes, then the trapezoidal rule is a compatible choice.

The error of composite trapezoidal rule with uniform step size $h$ is $O(h^2)$. It is not necessary to use the exact values of the integrand, approximations will do if they are sufficiently accurate. Suppose that your approximation of the integrand is $O(h^p)$ accurate. If $p>2$, then this extra accuracy is thrown out the window when you apply the trapezoidal rule. If $p<2$, then the approximation of the integral will not be $O(h^2)$ accurate as we cannot make gold from straw. The sensible choice is therefore $p=2$ which is why linear interpolation is a good choice.

Comment: Hi Carl, thank you very much. By selecting a new set of nodes, do you mean I select the numbers between 0 to 4 for z since both are the functions of z?

Comment: @RoshanShrestha You are correct. This is exactly what you should do.